# Can I fly to Thailand with an I-327 US Travel Document?

Tags: visas, usa, thailand

I'm currently a US Permanent Resident going through my naturalization process this year. In the meantime, I have an I-327  US Travel Document and Re-Entry Permit. I know I can re-enter into the US. But can I fly to Thailand? Do I need a tourist visa? My trip is only 13 days. Thank you!

[image: Photo of my Travel Document]

Comment: Do you have a passport from your country of citizenship?

Comment: No, i came here in 1990, parents left to get away from communism. Which put me in a limbo state. My nationality is STATELESS.

Comment: Depending on your parents' citizenship, you may actually be a citizen of that country.  Being naturalized in the US does not necessarily cause you to lose the citizenship of other countries, so you might want to look into this.  You never know when it could come in handy.

Comment: My parents are both US citizens now. Normally the parents pay and have all their children become citizens but that wasn't an option for us financially.

Comment: Perhaps I should have written "depending on your parents' original citizenship."  The fact that they are now US citizens is not likely to be relevant, especially since they did not include you when they naturalized.  For example, if they were Polish, then you almost certainly would still be a Polish citizen (as would they).  If they were Chinese then they likely would have lost their Chinese citizenship when they naturalized, if not before, but you would remain Chinese until you naturalize.

Comment: @JK: "Normally the parents pay and have all their children become citizens but that wasn't an option for us financially." There is no such thing as "pay for children to become US citizens". If you were a US permanent resident and under 18 when they naturalized, then you automatically became a US citizen. There is no process or application or payment; it is automatic and involuntary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thailand DOES accept a US I-327 Re-Entry Permit in lieu of a passport, however you WILL require a visa in order to travel to Thailand using that document. On your return to the US, the US will obviously also accept the I-327 for re-entry.

You will also need to consider your route from the US to Thailand as not all countries will let you transit using only an I-327 - you may require a visa or may not be allowed transit at all through some countries.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Do you know of any official websites that confirm this? I already have my 2-way ticket for March of this year and a place to stay so a Visa will not be a problem. Ive been searching for an answer since about June of last year, including calling Embassys and just walking into our air port and asking. NO ONE seems to know what a Travel Document. If you are correct then i need to buy you a Coke or something because you may have just made my year. I would really appreciate to know where you found this information. Thank you again.

Comment: You need a visa, and that visa goes in your travel document.  The fact that the Thai consulate issues such a visa is your proof that you can travel with that document!

Comment: You have a good point. It is an option on the application. It just confuses me when high officials at the airport  say "absolutely not, you will need a US Passport, no exceptions" ...And would i be good with just checking "Tourist Visa" option? Thank you again.

Comment: @JK what officials at what airport said that?

Comment: I i’ve gone to the PDX (Portland Oregon Airport) and explained my situation to different airlines, they never recognize the Travel Document, they bring in their high ups, and either say the safe bet a US Passport (which is obvious) or tell me to contact USCIS or boarder patrol, after that it depends you i get on the phone. And the same circle starts, they say US passport, give me another phone number which often leads back to the start. This “stack exchange” community has been the most help by far.